# In Rails, how to display value of a hash in text_area?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

I have a method in the User model to scan the authorized_keys file and identify which public keys belongs to a user. It does something like this:

```
def public_keys
  @public_keys = []
  # some file processing
  public_key = { "key" => "ssh-rsa foo.....", "account_on_machine" => "foo@bar" }
  @public_keys << public_key
end
```

In my view, I'm able to dump the values, but it looks absolutely messy:

```
<% @user.public_keys.each do |public_key| %>
  <%= public_key["account_on_machine"] %><br />
  <%= public_key["key"] %><br />
<% end %>
```

I believe the better way to display it is to dump `public_key["key"]` into a text_area. I don't really have a clue how. Can any one help?

Comment: Why a text area? "How" is obvious; `<textarea rows='whatever' cols='whatever'><%= public_key["key"] %></textarea>`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Rails helper for a text field. I'd probably make a content helper to handle figuring out what parts of your hash you want to display, but let's say that you've got everything assigned to a variable `display_text`. The text area helper, then, is `<%= text_area_tag('keys-text-area', display_text') %>`